# Django Improper URL NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, html, django

URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    #PAPER PROJECTS
    path('create-paper-project/', PTCreateView.as_view(), name='pt-create'),
    path('list-paper-projects/', PTListView.as_view(), name='pt-list'),
    path('pproj<str:pk>/', PTDetailView.as_view(), name='pt-detail'),
    path('pprojp<str:pk>/update/', PTUpdateView.as_view(), name='pt-update'),
    path('pproj<str:pk>/delete/', PTDeleteView.as_view(), name='pt-delete'),
]
```

VIEWS

```
class PTCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = PaperTool
    template_name = 'papertools/pt_create.html'
    success_url = '/paper-tools/list-paper-projects/'
    fields = ['title']

class PTListView(generic.ListView):
    model = PaperTool
    template_name = 'papertools/pt_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class PTDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = PaperTool
    template_name = 'papertools/pt_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class PTUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = PaperTool
    fields = ['title']
    template_name = 'papertools/pt_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('paper:pt-detail', kwargs={'pk': model.pk})

class PTDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = PaperTool
    template_name = 'papertools/pt_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('paper:pt-detail')
```

HTML

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'pt-detail' object_list.paper.pk %}">
          Paper Project Home
</a>
```

I continuously get the following error: "Reverse for 'pt-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['paper\-tools/pproj(?P[^/]+)/$']"
In the HTML portion if I replace the "object_list.paper.pk" portion with just a pk (say 6). This works just fine. I can even plug in other pk's to the URL. I do not understand why this is giving off an error. There seem to be similar problems on StackOverflow but none exactly like this.

Comment: How about changing it to int? `<int:pk>` ?

Comment: I've attempted this and received the same error.

Comment: If anyone has sine idea as to the solution I would appreciate any suggestions. This has been a thorn in my side for a hot minute now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a path in your urls.py called pt-detail configured correctly
You are calling it in your template ="{% url 'pt-detail'object_list.paper.pk %}"

You just need to make a small adjustment in your urls.py

like this ..

```
path('pt-detail/<str:pk>', PTDetailView.as_view(), name='pt-detail'),
```

NOT like This...

```
path('pproj<str:pk>/', PTDetailView.as_view(), name='pt-detail'),
```

Comment: This is not the answer. It returns with the same error. Additionally, when constructing URLs in HTML with Django when I call "{ url 'pt-detail' } pk" the "pt-detail" portion calls on the name='pt-detail' portion of the path.